# How to resize a pane to occupy a certain percentage of a whole tmux window?

Tags: tmux

I recently started to use tmux and likes it a lot.  I'd like to know how to set the size of my panes using percentage.  For example, there are 3 panels in a row, and I'd like to set the 1 pane to occupy 20% of the window width, and the other 2 panes each occupy 40% of the window width.  But so far, I could only find commands below.

```
Ctrl+B Alt+Arrow
- Resize the active pane

resize-pane -R 20
-  Resizes the pane right by 20 cells
```

Any better ways to do it?

Answer (score 5):

There is no -p flag for resize-pane, which is what you are really after, although it has been on the todo list for a while. Instead you will need to use -x or -y and work out the sizes yourself, for example a shell script like:

```
W=$(tmux display -p '#{window_width}')
L=$(expr $W \* 2 / 10)
R=$(expr $W \* 4 / 10)
tmux resizep -t{left} -x $L
tmux resizep -t{right} -x $R
```

Another alternative would be to set up a layout like you want then get the layout string (you can see it in "tmux lsw"), then you can reapply it to a different window with the same number of panes using "tmux selectl ...").

Answer (score 2):

`resizep` now supports percentages!

I like to have the left 2/3s of my terminal for vim, so I can do:

```
tmux resizep -t{left} -x "66%"
```

I bound `Ctrl-b =` to do this:

```
bind -r = resizep -t"{left}" -x "66%"
```